# Replacing multiple parts of a string with params passed into method

Tags: javascript, string

I have a function called `translate` that looks something like this:

```js
export const translate = (sentence: string, ...words) => { ... }
```

It looks into the settings to see what language is selected and then looks up the translated sentences dictionary.

Here is an example sentence: `"Each __ provides __ money"`.

After translating the sentence into the correct language, I want to check to see if there are any `__` in the string. That is what the param `...words` is for. We would then replace the `__` using the param `words`

Example of me using the function: `translate('Each __ provides __ money', 'Person', 'Fifty')` would return: `Each Person provides Fifty money`but translated.

Im currently having a problem with how to go about replacing the `__`.

I was thinking about doing something with `.split`:

```js
if (sentence.includes('__')) {
  let rebuiltSentence = ''
  const splitSentence = sentence.split('__')
  
  for (let i = 0; i < splitSentence.length; i++) {
    const part = splitSentence[i]
    rebuiltSentence += part
    rebuiltSentence += words[i]
  }

  return rebuiltSentence
}
```

But this seems a bit hacky to me. Is there any way I can maybe get the index of each `__` then replace it with the correct word index in the `words` param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String#replace` with a regex pattern and a callback that iterates the `words` array:

```js
const translate = (sentence, ...words) => {
  let i = 0;
  return sentence.replace(/\b__\b/g, () => words[i++]);
};

console.log(translate("Each __ provides __ money", "Person", "Fifty"));
```

If it should handle the situation when there aren't enough words to fit the blanks:

```js
const translate = (sentence, ...words) => {
  let i = 0;
  return sentence.replace(/\b__\b/g, m =>
    i < words.length ? words[i++] : m
  );
};

console.log(translate("Each __ provides __ money", "Person"));
```

Or using `split`, a bit closer to the spirit of your original approach:

```js
const translate = (sentence, ...words) =>
  sentence
    .split(/\b__\b/g)
    .map((e, i) => i === 0 ? e : (words[i-1] || "__") + e)
    .join("")
;

console.log(translate("Each __ provides __ money", "Person", "Fifty"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some i18n js libraries. For example, i18next (I chose only this one because I had a chance to work with it, you can also try other libraries). With i18next you can define translations in which selected fragments can be dynamically set, also with the results of other translations. Below is a simple example:

```js
void async function main() {
    await i18next.init({
        lng: 'en',
        resources: {
            en: {
                translation: {
                    'someKey': 'Each {{name}} provides {{number}} money',
                    'fifty': 'Fifty',
                },
            },
            pl: {
                translation: {
                    'someKey': 'Każdy {{name}} zapewnia {{number}} pieniędzy',
                    'fifty': 'pięćdziesiąt',
                },
            },
        },
    });

    console.log(i18next.t('someKey', { name: 'Person', number: i18next.t('fifty') }));

    await i18next.changeLanguage('pl');

    console.log(i18next.t('someKey', { name: 'Person', number: i18next.t('fifty') }));
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/i18next/dist/umd/i18next.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, you are not forced to define your translations in one place, you can break them into separate files that are then pulled from the server in case of a language change. See the [documentation](https://www.i18next.com/overview/getting-started) for more information, if you are interested :)